# Accessing an Array variable through a session

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array stored in a session like so

```
            $front_door_array = Array (
                                        "front_door_model" => $_SESSION['front_door'],
                                        "front_door_qty"   => $_SESSION['front_qty']
                                      );

            $_SESSION['front_door_array'] = $front_door_array;
```

I now need to access `front_door_model` and `front_door_qty` on another page through the session but am unsure how to. Normally I'd just do something like `$front_door_array['front_door_qty'];` but I don't know how to do this through the session.

Comment: `$_SESSION['front_door_array']['front_door_model']`

Comment: Well that was very simple, thanks @MichaelBerkowski

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `$_SESSION['front_door_array']` variable :)

Comment: Yeah I had thought of this but just wanted to learn if there was a way to do it through the session. Ta!

Comment: This is the way to do it through the session, $_SESSION is a global array variable, you can add as many keys as you want and then access it again from another script in the same session.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$_SESSION['front_door_array']['front_door_model']
```

To see all the values assigned in session :

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
```